# Pebbling a Checkerboard with Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to teach myself Dynamic Programming, and ran into this problem from MIT.

We are given a checkerboard which has 4 rows and n columns, and
has an integer written in each square. We are also given a set of 2n pebbles, and we want to
place some or all of these on the checkerboard (each pebble can be placed on exactly one square)
so as to maximize the sum of the integers in the squares that are covered by pebbles. There is
one constraint: for a placement of pebbles to be legal, no two of them can be on horizontally or
vertically adjacent squares (diagonal adjacency is ok).

(a) Determine the number of legal patterns that can occur in any column (in isolation, ignoring
the pebbles in adjacent columns) and describe these patterns.
Call two patterns compatible if they can be placed on adjacent columns to form a legal placement.
Let us consider subproblems consisting of the rst k columns 1  k  n. Each subproblem can
be assigned a type, which is the pattern occurring in the last column.

(b) Using the notions of compatibility and type, give an O(n)-time dynamic programming algorithm for computing an optimal placement.

Ok, so for part a: There are 8 possible solutions.

For part b, I'm unsure, but this is where I'm headed:
SPlit into sub-problems. Assume i in n.
1. Define Cj[i] to be the optimal value by pebbling columns 0,...,i, such that column i has pattern type j. 
2. Create 8 separate arrays of n elements for each pattern type.

I am not sure where to go from here. I realize there are solutions to this problem online, but the solutions don't seem very clear to me.

Comment: I only see 7 possible solution for part a can you explain all 8 possible solution?

Comment: Legal Column Arrangements: [-|-|-|-] ; [X|-|-|-] ; [-|X|-|-] ; [-|-|X|-] ; [-|-|-|X] ; [X|-|X|-] ; [X|-|-|X] ; [-|X|-|X] (answered for completeness sake)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track.  As you examine each new column, you will end up computing all possible best-scores up to that point.

Let's say you built your compatibility list (a 2D array) and called it **L<sub>i</sub>[y]** such that for each pattern **i** there are one or more compatible patterns **L<sub>i</sub>[y]**.

Now, you examine column **j**.  First, you compute that column's isolated scores for each pattern **i**.  Call it **S<sub>j</sub>[i]**.  For each pattern **i** and compatible 
pattern **x = L<sub>i</sub>[y]**, you need to maximize the total score **C<sub>j</sub>** such that **C<sub>j</sub>[x] = C<sub>j-1</sub>[i] + S<sub>j</sub>[x]**.  This is a simple array test and update (if bigger).

In addition, you store the pebbling pattern that led to each score.  When you update **C<sub>j</sub>[x]** (*ie* you increase its score from its present value) then remember the initial and subsequent patterns that caused the update as **P<sub>j</sub>[x] = i**.  That says "pattern **x** gave the best result, given the preceding pattern **i**".

When you are all done, just find the pattern **i** with the best score **C<sub>n</sub>[i]**.  You can then backtrack using **P<sub>j</sub>** to recover the pebbling pattern from each column that led to this result.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What would this compatibility array look like?

Comment: @user2767074: You need to construct it once in a preprocessing step, by testing every pattern against every other pattern. You could alternatively use an 8x8 2D array of bits or Boolean values -- this would be faster for queries like "Can pattern x follow pattern y?", and the algorithm can be tweaked to use such queries, but the queries it most naturally uses are "What is the set of patterns that can follow pattern y?", and it's faster to use an array of lists of valid patterns for this.

Comment: I left out implementation details so as not to clutter my answer.  I envisaged each row in the array containing a compatible pattern index, using a sentinel value (like -1) to mark the end of the row.  You could instead use 0 to mark the end of the list (assuming 0 is your zero-pebbles pattern), because every pattern is compatible with that.  You can pre-generate this on paper if you like.

Comment: Here's an open-ended question...  What if you have less than **2n** pebbles?  What modifications would you make to this algorithm? Is it still possible to have a time complexity of **O(n)**?